# Series expanison $\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^n}{(4n)!}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Which trigonometric function has the following Taylor series at $0$:
$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^n}{(4n)!}?
$$
Most likely it is going to be product of some usual trigonometric function and the hyperbolic ones.

Comment: I'd work on $\sum x^{4n}/(4n)!$ first. The buzzword is "series multisection".

Comment: According to WolframAlpha the solution is:

$$\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^n}{(4n)!} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(\sqrt[4]{x}) + \cosh(\sqrt[4]{x})\right)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x) = \sum_{n} \frac{x^n}{(4n)!}\quad \implies \quad f(x^4) = \sum_{n} \frac{x^{4n}}{(4n)!}$$

$$\cos(x) = \sum_{n}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}\quad \quad\cosh(x) = \sum_{n}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

$$\cos(x) + \cosh(x) = \sum_{n}\frac{(1 + (-1)^n)x^{2n}}{(2n)!} = 2\sum_{n}\frac{x^{4n}}{(4n)!}$$

$$\cos(x) + \cosh(x) = 2f(x^4)\quad \implies\quad f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(\sqrt[4]{x}) + \cosh(\sqrt[4]{x}))$$